# Property Description incorrect Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code. I am misleading by the property description shown in the pic below.
Is something wrong with my installed extension?

It work fine with maxlength code but the description is misleading.

[image]

Comment: what is misleading? It just shows the type of the property: an array that contains a string or number

Comment: I use to work on Visual Studio. It shows the details of the property, like Sub Attachment .New(fileName As String)( + 5 overloads) So I am confused with the above message.

Comment: you show the tooltip for a property and you comment with the tooltip of a method with overloads